# Altitude change with pitch angle

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Math is not my side at all, this is probably basic... I was wondering how one would find approximately how much an airplane has gone up or down in altitude given the speed and pitch angle.

Say for example, 2000 km/h speed and an upward angle of 7 degrees. So the increase in height after say, 1 minute is "?" Hope that was clear enough of a question.

I know there are many factors such as winds but I'm not looking to find the altitude change for airplanes, that was just an example to clarify my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distance $d$ traveled in a time of $t$ is given by:
$$d=vt$$ where $v$ is the aircraft speed.
The altitude change is given by:
$$\Delta h= d\sin(\alpha)$$ where $\alpha$ is the pitch angle.